# Cleaning up validator class

Tags: php, optimization

I updated my class with more functionality, but I kind if feel like it's a mess or that it can at least be improved by a bit readability, efficiency and/or DRY wise.

Anybody who could see if that can be done?

Any other suggestions are also welcome.

```
class Validator
{
    private $errors = [];
    private $rules  = [];

    public function getErrors($rulename = null)
    {
        if ($rulename) {
            return isset($this->errors[$rulename]) ? $this->errors[$rulename] : null;
        }

        return $this->errors;
    }

    # rules will be checked against in order as specified
    public function setRule($name, Array $rules, $required = true)
    {
        if (!array_key_exists($name, $this->rules)) {
            foreach ($rules as $rule) {
                if (!$rule instanceof IRule) {
                    throw new Exception('Array must only contain instances of IRule.');
                }
            }

            $this->rules[$name]['rules'] = $rules;

            if ($required === true) {
                $this->rules[$name]['required'] = 'Must not be null or empty.';
            } elseif ($required === false) {
                $this->rules[$name]['required'] = false;
            } else {
                $this->rules[$name]['required'] = (String) $required;
            }
        } else {
            throw new Exception(sprintf('Rule %s already exists.', $name));
        }
    }

    public function validate($rulename, $input)
    {
        if ($this->rules[$rulename]['required']) {
            if (empty($input)) {
                $this->errors[$rulename][] = $this->rules[$rulename]['required'];
            }

            foreach ($this->rules[$rulename]['rules'] as $rule) {
                try {
                    $rule->check($input);
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    $this->errors[$rulename][] = $e->getMessage();
                }
            }

            if (isset($this->errors[$rulename])) {
                return false;
            }
        } elseif (!empty($input)) {
            foreach ($this->rules[$rulename]['rules'] as $rule) {
                try {
                    $rule->check($input);
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    $this->errors[$rulename][] = $e->getMessage();
                }
            }

            if (isset($this->errors[$rulename])) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    public function dump()
    {
        print_r($this->rules);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good work formatting and approaching styles in a fashionable method, it makes reading your code very easy! a couple things to note:

- It's common to see `private` variables prefixed with an underscore to improve readability. It's up to you if you want to implement this, and if you use a framework, check their docs to see if it's standard.
- Regarding your last method, `dump()`: the name dump could mean many things. Without seeing the source, what's it dumping? It'd be fine to leave it as is, but you may consider renaming to `dumpRules()` or something of that sort.
- I'm not sure if you left it out, or you just haven't, but it's also a good practice to document your code. That means add comments. Googling PHPDoc will give you a good start, and if your familiar with JavaDocs, that's what I'm talking about.

---

Be careful making new array's with just `= []`.

> As of PHP 5.4 you can also use the short array syntax, which replaces
>   array() with [].

That's from the docs. So if anyone using below 5.4 wants your code, they could experience some turbulence setting it up.

---

The one comment you do have, is started with `#`. I believe this style of comments are deprecated and the C style comments (`/*...*/`, `//`) are favorable. I'll try and find a reference to this claim.

---

I noticed you have

```
foreach ($this->rules[$rulename]['rules'] as $rule) {
    try {
        $rule->check($input);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $this->errors[$rulename][] = $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

a couple times. You could put this in a function (with appropriate parameters) and simply call the function to reduce multiplicities.

---

Other than that, all looks well. Just in case you wanted to look at some other validation classes (if you haven't already), [here's one](https://github.com/Respect/Validation) to get you started.

Comment: This will be my personal code, I won't share it with anyone. That's the reason why I haven't commented as well. I only comment where I feel it would be necessary. As far as my dump method, it's actually just something quick I put there for developing/debugging purposes to see what's going on, I plan on removing that later. Thank you for your review!

Comment: @KidDiamond Even if it's personal code, I don't see why that should stop you from documenting it. It could make using it in a year *a lot* easier! I had a feeling the `dump()` was temporary, it's fine then.

Comment: Yeah, makes sense. I'm gonna look into PHPDoc. Also, I changed the `if .. elseif .. else` in my `setRule()` method with a `switch()` which slightly improved the readability.

Answer (score 3):

Two remarks considering the design of the current approach.

While checking the rules an exception is thrown to indicate that the rule is violated. Thus, exceptions are used as control-flow, which is [considered an anti-pattern](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/189222/are-exceptions-as-control-flow-considered-a-serious-antipattern-if-so-why). Why not have the `check` method return a `boolean` and give `IRule` a `getErrorMessage` method?

Secondly, the `Validator` class now also contains the logic for required fields. Why not create an `RequiredRule` which contains this logic? This would make your `validate` and `setrule` methods considerably simpler.

Comment: Nice one on the exceptions part, I will change that. As far as the `Required` rule class, I had one called `NotEmpty` but I got rid of it. Because if I left it out (for the field to be optional), the validator was still checking against the rest of the declared rules instead of just returning true. That's why I fused the required rule logic with the validator otherwise **all** my rule classes would need an extra argument to specify if the input is  optional or not. I posted a [question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24341304/1115367) specifically for that.

Comment: That makes sense. Note that documenting this type of design decision might help you to understand why you did it like this in the future.